# APIv4 Google sheet open sheet by name

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api

How do I open a sheet by name instead of by ID using the new APIv4? Seems like all the example have `spreadsheetID=key` and don't see how to do it by name. I need to open the sheet by name and get the ID.

Essentially what I'm trying to do is to manipulate a new sheet once it has been copied using the code below:

`drive.auth.service.files().copy(fileId= g.tkey,body={"parents": [{"kind": "drive#fileLink","id": g.mfolder}], 'title': copy_name}).execute()`

the new sheet with have a name `copy_name`, how do I get the ID of that sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At Google Sheets API v4, it cannot open directly spreadsheet from the file name. All APIs for Sheet API v4 are requires the spreadsheetId to use sheets. But you can retrieve the spreadsheetId using the file name. So you can open the spreadsheet from the file name by retrieving the spreadsheetId using the file name.

In order to retrieve spreadsheetId from the file name, it uses [Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/). The python script is as follows. Drive API v3 is used for it. It may add a scope (`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`).

**Script :**

```
res = service.files().list(q="trashed=false and name='" + copy_name + "'", fields="files(id)").execute()
```

**Result :**

```
{'files': [{'id': '#####'}]}
```

You can retrive the result as JSON. Using this ID, you can use spreadsheet.

Comment: I'm getting a `"Invalid query"` HttpError.

Comment: I figure it out... it should be `res = drive.auth.service.files().list(q="title='" + copy_name + "'", fields="items(id)").execute()`. Might be a different version of the API. Fields syntax also changed.

Comment: Using ``title`` and ``items`` for file name and the array is version 2. I'm sorry I couldn't notice it.

Comment: @pinoyyid Thank you for your help. I have forgot about trash box.